# Calling GRASS 6 in GRASS 7 (shell)

Tags: grass-gis, batch, shell

I am running a shell script for batch processing in GRASS 7 (calling it with sh [...sh] in the command line window), which creates a series of rasters through classifications, raster calculator and regression analysis. 
What I would like to do now is extend that script, so that it calculates the surface roughness of the resulting raster. r.roughness only works so far in GRASS 6, however. I have GRASS 6 installed as well.

Is it possible to call GRASS 6 and its extensions with the GRASS 7 command line without starting GRASS 6 or do I have to write a script that calls both programs from outside of either GRASS environments?

Comment: The basic set of environment variables used to define a GRASS session are the same in GRASS 6 and 7, so I don't think you can start GRASS 6 within GRASS 7 without making havok. I would use the batch processing setup to first build a 7 environment, do what you have to there, then redefine a 6 environment, and continue there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module needs to be ported to GRASS GIS 7, i.e. ideally rewritten as Python script. You may consider to contact the author for this (see manual page).

However: The script may still be run in GRASS 7 by just copying the files into the right places, i.e. into the scripts/ directory of the GRASS installation.

Comment: Hi! After some long trying around - I manage to get parts of the script to run in Grass 7. I found, however, Landserf to provide an even better solution for calculating terrain roughness.